# Navigation bar made of links not horizontal

Tags: html, css, navbar

So I've spent today messing around with code, trying different styles and whatnot. Right now I've tried to change it to make a navigation bar made of links go horizontal, but no matter what I try the links are vertical*. Cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

What I am trying to achieve is leaving the links that are Home, Food, Animals, and Verbs where they are, and make the alphabet links go across the page next to where it says "Home".

**CSS**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: ghostwhite;
}

header {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
  color: rosybrown;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-size: 55px;
}


nav.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px solid honeydew;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

a {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  background: ghostwhite;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: cadetblue;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li.active a {
  color: black;
  background: ghostwhite;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav.alphabet {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav.alphabet ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav.alphabet li {
  display: inline;
}

nav.alphabet a {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
}

**HTML**
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter|Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Italian Glossary</h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="italianhomepage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="italianfood.html">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Animals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Verbs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="alphabet">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">J</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">K</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">N</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">O</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">U</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">V</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to make them horizontal, but no matter what you do, they are horizontal? (I get that's probably a typo, but still :P) Please clarify exactly what you want to do, what you've tried, etc. as this is all pertinent to us helping you out.

Comment: Try changing your `nav.alphabet li {display:inline;}` style to `nav.alphabet li {display: inline-block;}`

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada That did make it vertical, but now I cannot make them aligned with where it says "Home"

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada Never mind! Just had to change the width. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @zavly : Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to align the two nav's side by side, you can edit your style to these:

```
nav.navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

and

```
nav.alphabet {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use display: inline
http://jsfiddle.net/xme6xnL4/

```
ul > li {
    display: inline;
}
```